# Are HTML DOM elements stored by reference in Javascript array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a custom JavaScript object and I want it to be "linked" with an element from the DOM.

```
var my_object = {}
var element = document.getElementsByClassName("a_class")[7];
my_object["element"] = element;
```

As I will need many of these objects, I wondered if directly storing DOM object obtained from `.getElement()` was a good idea?

I am scared that this will construct heavy objects. Is it the case, or does Javascript use some kind of clever and light references?

Alternatively, I thought to add a custom `id` to the element before stroring this `id` but this is less convenient.

Comment: There is no object creation... we are just storing a reference to an exisitng object

Comment: You are not actually storing the element but instead creating a cacheable reference to the element at hand.

Comment: @ArunPJohny Thank you, this is all I wanted to heard.

Comment: @ArunPJohny Do you know if it works the same way with object got using jQuery?

Comment: jQuery creates a jQuery object... but the internal dom references will be the same.... so even that overhead will be very low unless you are dealing with 10s of 1000s of jQuery object

Comment: Note: Retrieving objects is not inherently slow. `console.log` is slow as it does a lot of work to dump an object. The answer by @Grimbode is a far better option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, if you store an HTML DOM element into an object, you are storing its reference.

This is good practice because imagine if you have to access an element multiple times, rather than finding that `element` every single time, get it once and store it.

The process of finding an `element` is a lot less efficient compared to retrieving it through an `object`, especially if you use `jQuery`.

It does not take up a lot of memory, but this doesn't mean you should be storing every single `HTML element` on your page in an `object`.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript just saves it as a reference.

The object is not dereferenced until you retrieve data.

Like `console.log([reference to dereference and log])`

There is no slow down until the data is dereferenced

Comment: The object already exists in this example, so what do you mean by "The object *is not created* until you retrieve data.". Also why on Earth are you mentioning *slowdowns on deferencing*? Aside from the first sentence, this looks like a  random assortment of comments that have no real meaning.

Comment: bc console.log takes forever

Comment: woops i was confusing i fixed it

Comment: What has `console.log` got to do with the question asked?

Comment: nothing just a good example on how retrieving data from inside something is slow

Comment: `console.log` is slow... "retrieving data" is *not* slow. This should not be the accepted answer as it has too many misleading statements. Sorry